# Get the name of an element in vector in R? without the element's name

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to get the name of an element in the vector by order, meaning:

```
names_dates <- c(Mary = "1/1/1990", Joe = "1/1/1993")
```

I'd like to get `Mary` or `Joe` without knowing the name `Mary`, only by order, the first or second element. Thank you!
Mary and not "Mary" wo. " "

EDIT: solved
names(names_dates)[1] <- "old"
names(names_dates)[2] <- "new"

Answer (score 1):

do you mean this?

```r
names_dates <- c(Mary = "1/1/1990", Joe = "1/1/1993")
x <- noquote(names(names_dates[1]))

x
#> [1] Mary

class(x)
#> [1] "noquote"

typeof(x)
#> [1] "character"
```

Note that `x` is now a `noquote` class which is a class built over the type `character`.

---

However, the only reason you see ".." it's because character are supposed to be printed that way, therefore if you need to filter, **chances are you don't need to use `noquote`!**

---

If you use `cat` you will not see them, because `cat` is coded not to show them.

```
cat(names(names_dates[1]))
#> Mary
```

However, you cannot assign it:

```
x <- cat(names(names_dates[1]))
x
#> NULL
```

Because `cat` returns `NULL` invisibly (check out `?invisible`).

Comment: Sorry, actually it is 
names_dates <- c(Mary = "1/1/1990", Joe = "1/1/1993")
and in need Mary and not "Mary", wo  " "

Comment: I dont understand the difference.

Comment: for filter function in need without  " "

Comment: is this what you were looking for?